# WebStorm 2018.1 sub-folder collapse feature gone

Tags: webstorm

Recently updated my WebStorm to version 2018.1 and a feature I liked is missing from what I can see. It's the collapse subfolders when collapsing a folder on the project panel.

I've been able to collapse all sub folders without the need to collapse the whole project. Once I reopened that folder, all the subfolders were closed. Now this feature is gone or I must change my settings.

Does anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: Project Files can be used as an alternative to Project before a fix is released. Sub-nodes collapsing works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for [IDEA-186081](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186081) to be notified on any progress with it. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135 if you are not familiar with YouTrack.